# LWJGL text problems and framerate drops

Tags: java, fonts, lwjgl

in LWJGL I add text to my Display. When done, the program drops to about 1-2FPS. I have capped it with `Display.sync(60);`

Without text, it runs fine. With, absolutely... terrible?
Here is the source for my text:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Text {

private TrueTypeFont font2;

public void drawString(String font, String string, int x, int y, Color color) {

    // TODO: Fix extreme lag issues.

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(font);
        Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
        awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(24f); // set font size
        font2 = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);

        Color.white.bind();
        font2.drawString(x, y, string, color);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Dont exactly want to release my games source but heres the code that displays the text.

```
    // Initialization code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Text t = new Text();
    t.drawString("res/Minecraftia.ttf", "test", 0, 0, Color.yellow);
```

**Edit:**

```
    // Initialization code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        // Render


        init();
        input();
        grid.draw();
        drawSelectionBox();
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
private void init() {
    // This is what i'm meant to do????
    Text t = new Text();
    t.drawString("res/Minecraftia.ttf", "test", 0, 0, Color.white);
}
```

**Edit again: (Hope not too long)**

```
public Boot() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.setTitle("Test Program.");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    grid = new BlockGrid();

    // Initialization code OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    init();
    input();
    grid.draw();
    drawSelectionBox();
    Display.update();


    Text t = new Text();
    t.drawString("res/Minecraftia.ttf", "test", 0, 0, Color.white);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        // Render


        init();
        input();
        grid.draw();
        drawSelectionBox();
        //Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you read the whole font and create it in every render call.

```
public void drawString(String font, String string, int x, int y, Color color) {

try {
    //You create a new resource stream and load a file
    InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(font); // <-- slow

    //You create a new Fonts and load it out of the input stream
    Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream); // <-- extremely slow

    //You create a new TrueTypeFont out of it 
    awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(24f); // set font size
    font2 = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false); // <-- slow

    Color.white.bind();
    font2.drawString(x, y, string, color);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Instead, you should do the Font-loading only once in an init call and then just refer to the TrueTypeFont when rendering.

Remember that rendering is a very performance sensitive call and creating instances or streams and loading in that method (and in update(..), too) can drastically drop your FPS rate and should be avoided.

**Update**

Furthermore, you are creating a new instance of Text every rendering call too:

```
Text t = new Text();
t.drawString("res/Minecraftia.ttf", "test", 0, 0, Color.yellow);
```

Here too, create this once in the beginning or, better, just pass the String to draw to the drawString method instead of having a wrapper object like Text for that.

Comment: Ok, I have done that out of the while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) but now the entire screen goes green and the text doesn't appear.

Comment: @Sk4llsRPG Please updapte your question with the whole new code.

Comment: Done that, dont know if you want me to use init()?

Comment: You didn't really understand what I am going for - You are still calling init() every single frame in a loop. Initialize **once**.

Comment: Ok, will show you my Boot() class, please show me where to insert it.

Comment: Just somewhere in the startup/setup process.. And furthermore I meant that you are supposed to move the reading and loading that you are currently doing in the drawString() method to the init() method.

Comment: You still have the `init()` call within the while-loop. You have to remove it from there. It must be called **once** and only once.

Comment: What are you even doing? ;) The drawstring call out of the loop will not have any effect at all. There are three methods: init, update and render. In that order. And init is supposed to be used for initalizing and loading resources (loading the fonts, the code you now have in the drawString method which is called in render). Update is supposed to be for program logic, reacting on user input calculating movement and so on. Render is for rendering, and rendering **only**. Do **not** call init, load, setup-stuff in render or update! That is very important for the performance of your application.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have diagnosed the problem, it's just now that when I do it, the text appears behind everything else I have on the screen, everything else HAS to be in the while loop as they are constantly being updated but the Display.isCloseRequested is the last method, so everything is being added on top of it, any way I can display it last without having it int the 'shutdown' part of the code?

Comment: The things you render (draw) on the screen will appear in that exact order. So if you want your text to be on top, render it at last.

Comment: Yes, but in the loop, lags, outside just under, it is included with the shutdown code O.o

Comment: Of course it lags because you still have the loading code in the drawString method! Please try what I told you and then come back and report that went wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry, I am just SO confused with the initiation stuff, I got it now and its working fine, thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got it :) Here are a lot of tips and tutorials on LWJGL, OpenGL and game-creating: http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Learning_LWJGL